# How to bind ENUM to radiobutton?

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

*Type* is enum property in object.

jsp:

```
<form:radiobutton path="type" value="Male" />
```

java:

```
public enum TestType
{
    Male, Female;
}
```

and got error

*Unable to convert value 'Male' from type 'java.lang.String' to type 'java.lang.Enum'; reason = 'java.lang.Enum is not an enum type'*

Comment: My fault. The type was _Enum<TestType> type_
I change to _TestType type_ and it is OK!

Answer (score 4):

Do as follows

```
public enum TestType {

    MAN("Man"),
    FEMALE("Female");

    private String description;

    private TestType(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public String getValue() {
        return name();
    }

    public void setValue(String value) {}

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

}
```

And register a custom binder as follows

```
dataBinder.registerCustomEditor(TestType.class, new PropertyEditorSupport() {
        @Override
        public void setAsText(String value) throws IllegalArgumentException {
            if(StringUtils.isBlank(value))
                return;

            setValue(TestType.valueOf(value));
        }

        @Override
        public String getAsText() {
            if(getValue() == null)
                return "";

            return ((TestType) getValue()).name();
        }
    });
```

Then

```
<form:radiobuttons path="type" items="${testTypeList}" itemLabel="description"/>
```

You set up your TestType as follows

```
 model.addAttribute(TestType.values());
```

Comment: this solution worked for me in one shot ... only change for spring 3.0, remove the itemLabel property from <form:radiobuttons>

Comment: @harshit but how do you specify the itemlabel, the above method does not work for me ... ?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps, the `type` property of the command object is decalred as `Enum` instead of `TestType`?